# On finding a finite set of generators for a certain semigroup

Tags: semigroups, combinatorial-geometry, integer-lattices, discrete-geometry, algebraic-combinatorics

Let $A$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb Z^2$. Let $\mathbb ZA$ be the subgroup of $\mathbb Z^2$ generated by $A$. Let $\mathbb R_{+}, \mathbb Q_{+}$ denote the set of non-negative real and rational numbers respectively. Then I know that for some $a_1,...,a_n \in \mathbb ZA \cap \mathbb Q_{+} A$ , we have $\mathbb ZA \cap \mathbb Q_{+} A=\mathbb ZA \cap \mathbb R_{+} A=\mathbb Na_1+\cdots+\mathbb Na_n$ .

Here $\mathbb N$ is the set of non-negative integers.

My question is:

> If $A=\{ (0,4); (4,0); (1,3); (3,1)\}\subseteq \mathbb Z^2$, then how to find a finite set of generators for $\mathbb ZA \cap \mathbb Q_{+} A$ ?

i.e. how to find finitely many $a_1,...,a_n\in \mathbb ZA \cap \mathbb Q_{+} A$ such that $\mathbb ZA \cap \mathbb Q_{+} A=\mathbb Na_1+\cdots+\mathbb Na_n$ ?

NOTE: Just to clarify, $\mathbb Q_{+}A$ is the set of  all finite $\mathbb Q_{+}$-linear combination of elements of $A$ (and similarly for $\mathbb R_{+}A$ ... )

Comment: Aren't just the given vectors forming a generator system?

Comment: @Berci: I don't think so ... $(2,2)$ is in the final semigroup I've written but I don't think it can be gotten from $A$ only by $\mathbb N$-linear combination ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for all $(x,y)\in A$ you have $x+y\equiv0\pmod{4}$, so the same holds for all $(x,y)\in\Bbb{Z}A$. Moreover you have
$$(4,0),\ (3,1),\ (2,2),\ (1,3),\ (0,4)\in\Bbb{Z}A,$$
and of course
$$\Bbb{Q}_+^2\supseteq\Bbb{Q}^+A\supseteq\Bbb{Q}_+(4,0)+\Bbb{Q}_+(0,4)=\Bbb{Q}_+^2,$$
and from this it follows that
$$\Bbb{Z}A\cap\Bbb{Q}_+A=\Bbb{N}(4,0)+\Bbb{N}(3,1)+\Bbb{N}(2,2)+\Bbb{N}(1,3)+\Bbb{N}(0,4),$$
and it is not hard to see that this generating set is minimal. I leave the details of the above to you.

Comment: Could you please add a proof that why is every non-negative integer solution of $x+y=0$(mod $4)$ is a non-negative integer combination of $(4,0); (0,4); (1,3); (3,1)$ and $(2,2)$ ? Thanks ..

Comment: It follows simply from division by $4$ with remainder; write $x=4q_x+r_x$ and $y=4q_y+r_y$ with $0\leq r_x,r_y<4$. Then $r_x+r_y\equiv0\pmod{4}$, so $(r_x,r_y)$ is one of the above.

Comment: Take their remainders $x'$ and $y'$, then $x'+y'=4$ and thus it is among the given 5 elements (or $x'=y'=0$).